# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "[timecol: timestamp]" at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-mllib, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying parse date that is stored in cassandra database, but, when i parse the date, i receive the error message java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "[timecol: timestamp]". In database my date is in format "2015-08-21 04:01:00+0000". somebody can help me please?

```
    val conf = new SparkConf(true)
             .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1").setAppName("test")
             .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
             .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
             .set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val csc=new CassandraSQLContext(sc)

    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)


    import sqlContext.implicits._


   var imput: SimpleDateFormat   = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",  Locale.ENGLISH)
   var dia: SimpleDateFormat   = new SimpleDateFormat("dd")

   val data = csc.sql("SELECT timecol from smartgrids.analyzer_temp")
   val diacv = dia.format(imput.parse(data.toString()))
```

After execute the code i receive the following error message:

```
    data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timecol: timestamp]       java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "[timecol: timestamp]" 
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366) 
    at   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$    $iwC.<init>(<console>:66) 
    at    $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.    <init>(<console>:71) 
    at       $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.    <init>(<console>:73) 
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:75)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:77)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:79) 
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init> (<console>:81)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:83) 
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:85) 
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:87)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:89)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:91)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:93) 
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:95) 
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:97) 
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:99) 
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:101) 
    at <init>(<console>:103)
    at .<init>(<console>:107) 
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7) 
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065
```

Comment: I think you have to process the elements of the result, e.g. with `data.map(d => dia.format(imput.parse(d)))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I already tried apply this solution but it's give error       org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable at         org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304) at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294) at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)

Comment: Since `SimpleDateFormat` is serializable, I suspect that the problem lies somewhere else, but I'm not familiar enough with Spark to elaborate. Maybe the SerializationDebugger can help.